# How to draw filled rectangle in multiple images at a time in php?

Tags: php

I need to draw color filled rectangles in multiple images at the same time.

```
$path      = "D:\Images\sample.png";      
$result_path  = "D:\Images\output\sample_output.png";
$image        = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 700);
$image        = imagecreatefrompng($path);
$color        = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 181, 255, 1, 75);
imagefilledrectangle($image, 15, 15, 30, 30, $color);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image, $result_path);
imagedestroy($image);
```

This code helped to draw a filled rectangle in a single image.

Is it possible to draw filled rectangles on multiple images at the given co-ordinates of x and y?

Comment: You can make an array with paths and iterate over it?

Answer (score 0):

To draw multiple images in PHP from different requests at the same time you can't save the image to a static filename. $result_path should be NULL or your call to imagepng shouldn't include a second argument. It can be reduced to imagepng($image). The code you have posted will output the png to a file but it won't display the image.

Comment: the image name in $result_path will not be same for all. It will be provided dynamically for multiple images so that the images get created with different names in the resulting path.

Comment: In that case what Ravenix said is your solution. PHP doesn't have good multithreading support and the latest versions of PHP don't allow multithreading from the web (CGI). If you are executing this from a shell than you can use PHP threads extension to create the images concurrently.